# XmlSerializer preserve whitespace during serialization to XML

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm using XmlSerializer for Object -> Xml serialization. When a string property inside my object is empty or contains only whitespace the serializer just returns `<SomeProperty/>`.

How can I preserve whitespace during serialization?

And a followup, if I put multiple spaces `SomeProperty = "     ";` I want to serialize those too, so `<SomeProperty>     </SomeProperty>`.

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
var xmlWriterSetting = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default,
    Indent = false,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true
};

using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlWriterSetting))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, InputObject);
    return stringWriter.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. I get the whitespace back when I use your code (using VS 2015 and .NET 4.5.2). Could you post the class declarations as well? May be there is a difference there..

Comment: @Volkan Paksoy I found the problem, the code indeed does serialize correctly (preserves the whitespace correctly) however on the front-end I'm using an <asp:Xml> control with a default XSLT (used from Microsoft) to display the data - this control doesn't display correctly. I should have checked the debug in the beginning. Thanks for making me go into debug and check!

Answer (score 1):

You can control the whitespace handling in the XML itself. So you should write the property like this:

```
<SomeProperty xml:space="preserve">     </SomeProperty>
```

To do so, simply add the attribute by using the writer:

```
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xml", "space", null, "preserve");
```

When you read this XML back, the spaces will be considered as significant whitespaces and will be returned even if you ignore whitespaces in the reader's configuration.

Comment: Related to my question, but this would be for deserialization - extremely useful though, will save this for future use! Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this helps with `XmlSerializer`, do you?

Comment: @Ivan, Uporabnik003: You can implement `IXmlSerializable` for classes, which need such special handling. There you have a `WriteXml` method with an `XmlWriter` so you can add the attribute.

Comment: The point is that this is **not** a special handling - just string properties with whitespace. Anyway, the whole discussion and the answer are pointless in regard to `XmlSerializer` because `XmlSerializer` indeed keeps the whitespace inside the property values, thus does not need any control or special handling. As OP stated, the problem was different, so let stop here.